# Simple Angular 2 Plunker not working

Tags: angular, plunker

Trying to create simple `Hello World Angular 2` in `Plunker` but seems not working. This can be the stupid question but still ...

What I am doing wrong ?

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/edJkEXMowp7fkJQNtDQc/)

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use stack-blitz? It is ideal for Angular projects and initializes a simple app automatically.

Comment: Thanks !! Do you know whats wrong with plunker ?

Comment: To be honest no. I never use it with Angular

Comment: This is the weired error, I tried many things but no luck instead of that you can use stackblitz, codeSandBox, jsFiddle